# Windows clipboard ::GetClipboardData() for CF_DIBV5 causes the image on the clipboard to be modified and corrupted?

Tags: winapi, clipboard, ole

I found on (at least) Win10 that calling `::GetClipboardData()` on a CF_DIBV5 created via Alt-PrtScrn (may be a synthesized format) causes the image to be modified (and basically corrupted).

For example, on the handler for `ON_WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE()` the simple loop below will cause the corruption (note that you need to use debug mode so the ::GetClipboardData() is not optimized out).

To test, first don't run your app that processes the clipboard, use Alt-PrntScrn to capture data, then paste it to Paint.  Now run the app that process the clipboard (with below sample below). Repeat Alt-PrntScrn process and you'll see it's different where the right side of the captured window ends up on the left and not centered in the area.

```
void CMainFrame::OnClipboardUpdate()
    if (::OpenClipboard(AfxGetMainWnd()->m_hWnd)) {
        UINT uformat=0;
        while ((uformat=::EnumClipboardFormats(uformat))!=0) {
            if (uformat==CF_DIBV5) {
                // get the data - run in debug mode so not optimized out 
                HGLOBAL hglobal=::GetClipboardData(uformat);
            }
        }
        // clean up
        ::CloseClipboard();
    }
}
```

To enable the handler you need to call `AddClipboardFormatListener(GetSafeHwnd());` in something like `int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)` then `RemoveClipboardFormatListener(GetSafeHwnd());` on `void CMainFrame::OnDestroy()`

So is this a bug in Win10 (and other Windows Versions) or should I be doing something else that the sample isn't doing?  (I know other formats exist, but the CF_DBIV5 is what I wanted).

I'm on Version 1903 (OS Build 18362.838)

Note the sample pic has right side items on left and some garbage pixels in lower left.   I alt-prtscrn while app running, pasted in paint.

[image: sample pic]

My resolution is 2560x1600.

Here's a link to a project that will cause the problem:

[Sample Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hxbw23j1un2vxy7/clipissue.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Why are you using `EnumClipboardFormats()` to look for 1 format? You can use `IsClipboardFormatAvailable()` instead. Or, just call `GetClipboardData()` unconditionally and let it fail if the desired format is not available.

Comment: i deal with more formats, this was just extracted out to show the problem.

Comment: @df234987 I can't reproduce this issue on Windows 10 1909 build 18363.778. Could you show your Windows version and snapshot showing corrupted image?

Comment: added os version and sample pic.

Comment: I test on Windows 10 1903 (OS Build 18362.836), it also works for me. Is your *.838* a typo? And can you have a double check that if this issue is introduced by code lines in the `CMainFrame::OnClipboardUpdate()` you showed? For example, remove the body of  `CMainFrame::OnClipboardUpdate()`, can this issue is still be reproduced?

Comment: @df234987 garbage pixels: do you mean the 3 red, green and blue pixels in the very lower left corner?

Comment: **Rita** I upgraded last night to 1909 OS Build 18363.836 .. still see the issue.  **Jabberwocky** - yes those are garbage, if you look the whole left 3 pixels belongs on the right, and it may be up by one which would explain those garbage pixels (they would exist outside the actual image).  Let me create a basic project.

Comment: I've added a sample project which I confirmed causes the problem.

Comment: @df234987 What would be the steps to duplicate the problem with the sample project?

Comment: same process explained.   First, open paint and some other window to capture (I used word above), alt-prntscrn from that other window, paste in paint.   all good.   Run the sample project, repeat process, graphic is wrong (whole column of pixels from right side now on the left, with the garbage pixels in lower left corner).  You have to look closely and best to do it where the edges of the window have unique items on right and left (if all the same background won't see it).

Comment: @df234987 I don't see that here, in either win10 or win7. Maybe write a small app to simulate pasting into (instead of paint), and compare the binary data retrieved for the different formats with vs. without the OnClipboardUpdate calls in the main app.

Comment: @dxiv it was reported to me by others, so I know it does affect other systems.  You won't see a problem if you just do it on a plain background except for the 3 pixels.   Make the background on the right side of the window red and the left blue, you'll see the red line down the left side.

Comment: @df234987 Tried all that and more but still no, I don't see it here. This is *not* meant in any way to imply it doesn't happen, just that it doesn't happen on the two machines I had handy to try it on.

Comment: make sure running in debug mode or the inside of the loop will be optimized out.

Comment: @df234987 Thanks for your demo project. I can reproduce this issue now. But using `CF_DIB` instead of `CF_DIBV5` works for me.

Comment: Hopefully it will be fixed since isn't V5 supposed to be more precise?   To work around the bug using CF_DIB does it support alpha channel?  What do I lose using CF_DIB?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the following description in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/bitmap-header-types) :

> The red, green, and blue bitfield masks for `BI_BITFIELD` bitmaps
>   immediately follow the `BITMAPINFOHEADER`, `BITMAPV4HEADER`, and
>   `BITMAPV5HEADER` structures. The `BITMAPV4HEADER` and `BITMAPV5HEADER`
>   structures contain additional members for red, green, and blue masks
>   as follows.

[image]

When the `biCompression` member of `BITMAPINFOHEADER` is set to `BI_BITFIELDS` and the function receives an argument of type `LPBITMAPINFO`, the color masks will immediately follow the header. The color table, if present, will follow the color masks. `BITMAPCOREHEADER` bitmaps do not support color masks.

When you handle `CF_DIBV5` correctly you will draw the image successfully. The following is an example of Win32 C++ you can refer to:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static UINT uFormat = (UINT) -1;
    HDC hdcMem = NULL;
    RECT rc = {0};
    BYTE * pData = NULL;
    BITMAPV5HEADER *pDibv5Info = NULL;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE:
    {       
        if (IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_DIBV5))
        {
            uFormat = CF_DIBV5;

            ::CloseClipboard();

            GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, &rc, TRUE);
        }
    }
    break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            switch (uFormat)
            {
            case CF_DIBV5:
                hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
                if (hdcMem != NULL)
                {
                    if (::OpenClipboard(hWnd)) {
                            HANDLE hglobal = ::GetClipboardData(uFormat);
                            pData = (BYTE*)GlobalLock(hglobal);
                            if (pData)
                            {
                                pDibv5Info = (BITMAPV5HEADER *)pData;
                                int offset = pDibv5Info->bV5Size + pDibv5Info->bV5ClrUsed * sizeof(RGBQUAD);
                                if (pDibv5Info->bV5Compression == BI_BITFIELDS)
                                    offset += 3 * sizeof(DWORD); //three DWORD color masks that specify the red, green, and blue components

                                pData += offset;
                                SetDIBitsToDevice(hdc, 20, 20, pDibv5Info->bV5Width, pDibv5Info->bV5Height, 0, 0, 0, pDibv5Info->bV5Height, pData, (BITMAPINFO *)pDibv5Info, 0);
                            }

                        GlobalUnlock(hglobal);
                        ::CloseClipboard();
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
}
```

The correct image drawn in my application window:

[image]

I can reproduce the same issue without code:

```
if (pDibv5Info->bV5Compression == BI_BITFIELDS)
    offset += 3 * sizeof(DWORD);
```

The corrupted image:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sue what this had to do with the Windows bug reported?   I'm not drawing anything, doing anything except calling :`:GetClipboardData(CF_DIBV5);`. Once that is done, pasting the image to other apps is corrupt.   If you don't do that, it's fine.   So something internally in windows ::GetClipboardData() is corrupting something.  I'm not sure what MSPAINT uses, but it's corrupted by ::GetClipboardData().

Comment: @df234987 There is no issue need to report for clipboard APIs/documents. The clipboard has the correct data for `CF_DIBV5` so I can use that data draw the correct image. `GetClipboardData()` doesn't corrupt anything. It cause the system [converts an available format to the requested format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/clipboard-formats#synthesized-clipboard-formats). You see this issue because the converted format DIBV5 seems not supported by mspaint. Feel free let me know if you still have any concern.

Comment: Or maybe using CF_BITMAP or CF_DIB?  It seems it would ask for whatever format it wanted.  If you put a CF_DIBV5 on the clipboard and it asks for CF_BITMAP it gets back a CF_BITMAP.  So if the clipboard is converting it on `GetClipboardData()` then converting it back to CF_BITMAP or CF_DIB then perhaps that is the issue.  But something alters something, I doubt MSPAINT is going to request a different format.  Have you done that then tried the CF_BITMAP and CF_DIB version afterwards?

Comment: @df234987 There is only once conversion. If the requested format is match the available format, no conversion happens while if the requested format is not match the available format the conversion happens. We've no idea what format the print screen short cut gives us but it gives a format that mspaint supports. Also we've no idea what format the msprint requests but it seems not `CF_DIBV5`. `GetClipboardData(CF_DIB)` and `GetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP)` don't cause this issue.

Comment: Exactly, so it logically seems that `GetClipboardData(CF_DIBV5)` is altering the contents of the data returned by either `GetClipBoardData(CF_DIB)` or `GetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP)`.   Do you have a sample app that draw the image first from `CF_DIBV5`, then `CF_BITMAP` or `CF_DIB`.  My guess one of those two will be off otherwise MSPAINT wouldn't have a problem pasting (if it was using CF_DIBV5 it would be consistent).

Comment: @df234987d You are right. When the `CF_DIB` format is requested before `CF_DIBV5`, the data is retrieved correctly. However, when `CF_DIB` format is requested after `CF_DIBV5`, the data retrieved is wrong with an additional color mask table generated. I'll report this issue internally.